# ImageView on tableViewCell doesnt appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a tableView and you can add cells. and it doesnt show my image on the left hand side of the newly added cells. I'm using the default cell style and here is my code:
This is the button that allows us to add a cell.

```
- (IBAction)outlet1:(id)sender {
[cart.cells addObject:@"1"];
cart.cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle1.png"];
}
```

Please help! I checked the name of the image and it seems good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to place the image to the UITableViewCell inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, by setting the image to cell.imageView.image

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,  but i want to add different images for different added cells. How could i do this? THanks a lot!

Comment: If your use case is simple, just name the images paddle1.png, paddle2.png and so on. And inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, set them like this: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"paddle%d.png",indexPath.row+1]];

Comment: ok this is close, but have you seen the amazon app? I am trying to do something like the cart page on amazon's app. I want to add a cell with 1 image if one button is pressed. But if a different button is pressed, i want a new image. And i dont want them in a specific order? Thanks for the help!! DO you know how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok then. Inside your button action method place this: UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathofTheCellYouWishToAddImageTo]; And then set the image using cell.imageView.image

Comment: ok im adding this to a certain indexPath though. And im not sure when the user will press the button. SO im not sure which index to set this to? THanks!!

Comment: How do you decide that? Do you have different buttons? How do you actually decide pressing which button adds an image to which cell?

Comment: Yes i have like 6 buttons and i dont know which one will be pressed when. So i just want each button to add a cell and add a certain image. So in the end there will be lets say 4 newly added cells and each will have a different picture. And this is all on what the user decides. So its like when you shop online and when you add things to your cart. Thanks!! :D